# Assetic javascripts creating empty file from a non-empty source (inside bundle)

Tags: javascript, symfony, bundle, twig, assetic

I am using Assetic within a twig template to specify 2 JS files to utilize from my bundle

```
{
    % javascripts
        '@JiraExtendedReportsBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'
        '@JiraExtendedReportsBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js'
    %
}
```

When running `assetic:dump` and then `assets:install`, it creates the two files (without errors), but the second one is empty, even though it has contents within my bundle.

I've ensured that I have write access to web/bundles.
I've tried the `--symlink` option, which errors out.

What steps can I take to debug/fix this?

Update:
I just looked into web/bundles/jiraextendedreports/js and it's not creating an empty file for the second file, it's not creating a file at all.
I've tried downgrading to symfony 2.3.3 and 2.3.2 (from 2.3.6) with no change - I got the idea from this thread: https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/496, but it does not seem to apply to me

Comment: what error do you get with --symlink option?

Comment: Did you forgot the end of the tag ? `{
    % javascripts
        '@JiraExtendedReportsBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'
        '@JiraExtendedReportsBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js'
    %
}
 <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts  %}`

Answer (score 1):

```
{% javascripts
        '@JiraExtendedReportsBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js' 
        '@JiraExtendedReportsBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js'
    %}
         <script src="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

*reference:*
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files

**In Dev:**

```
php app/console cache:clear
php app/console assets:install
php app/console assetic:dump
```

**In Production:**

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
php app/console assets:install #not always necessary
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

*reference:*
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html#common-post-deployment-tasks
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22875441/3625883