# symfony2 Bundle public Resources URL

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have write a bundle that contains public assets: Images, CSS and Javascript.
Everything is stored in my bundle Resources/public/ folder.

I launch an ascetic command that generates symlinks in global web project folder.

My problem is my bundle name is visible in Images, CSS and Javascript URLs.
Is there a way to rewrite this URL.
I want to access to my CSS with this URL: http://mywebsite.com/mycustomfoldername/mycss.css

Second question: Is it a good thing to write directly files in global web project folder ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `Symfony`'s built in command `assets:install` command it will change:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

into:

```
<script src="/bundles/your-bundle/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But if you will use `Assetic` `assetic:dump` command (this is command provided by `AsseticBundle`) it will change:

```
{% javascripts '@YourBundleBundle/Resources/public/js/script.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

into (in production mode)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/as5s31l.js"></script>
```

And I guess it solves your issue of bundle name in url.

As for putting js files directly in main web folder: it is not good idea as everything should be bundle specific, all code sits in bundle so your assets should also.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22873164/difference-between-asseticdump-and-assetsinstall) answer for some additional explanation about difference between `assets:install` and `assetic:dump commands`

Comment: In your case (ascetic:dump), the URL is not correct because the js filename is changed. I think this is due to avoid filename collision.
I really want to get: <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>

Comment: if your script name will not be changed (``script.js``) you will have problems with changing anything - ``script.js`` will be stored in user browser's cache and it won't refresh after you change anything (since name is the same)

Answer (score 1):

Use assetic. In Twig template use:

```
{% stylesheets '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/app.css'
        '@MyBundle/Resources/public/css/additional.css'
        output='mycss.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Then use command: `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod`

In dev environment you'll see something like `http://yoursite.com/09516d4_mycss_1.css` but in production will be `http://yoursite.com/mycss.css`

Note that you must always use `assetic:dump` when your files was changed to see changes in production.

For fonts I use assetic config:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        font-awesome-otf:
            inputs: '@AppBundle/Resources/fonts/FontAwesome.otf'
            output: 'fonts/FontAwesome.otf'
```

You can try the same with images:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        image-background:
            inputs: '@AppBundle/Resources/images/back.jpg'
            output: 'images/back.jpg'
```

Comment: Great but how should i do for background image urls for example ? Thoses url are stored in css file. I can't put any {% %} in css files...

Comment: can you show sample of this in your answer for how the fonts and images are actually used? Like in the css file or html file etc...